# Node-Red Web Sockets

Tags: websocket, node-red

I have a node-red websocket input that accepts JSON describing how to query my database. I use the json to generate sql then use the sql query and output the result rows to the same socket.

The result rows are consumed as data for my google charts.

It worked well until I added second chart.

My html structure is:

- page

  - iframe1

    - google chart with js with wsconnect for that chart
  - iframe2

    - second chart with it's js with wsconnect for that chart

I anticipated that the connect to the NR flow would create an instance and the second would create another instance and the flows would not collide. It appears that the second chart/js gets the data from the first and the first gets it too.

[image: flow]

Can you give me a lead on where my problem is and a possible solution?

I want multiple ws connects to send different queries and to reveive their different row results.

Is it that my expectations for NR are too high? Can I name my ws-connection (didn't see that available).

Comment: Edit the question to include a screen shot of your flow or the exported json representation so we can see what you are actually doing.

Comment: OK, Now include the text in the function node.

Comment: The Function node uses the json to create the correct sql to query my database.  the next node in the flow does that query. finally the results set is returned to the requester. The problem I seem to have is that two different (json and sql) requests are running but both receive the same result set.

Comment: Yes, but I want to see if you are passing the input message through or creating a new message to send on

Comment: Thanks. The input message is a json description of data elements, aggregation and more but no sql, example: {"dategranularity":"dd"   , "nodes":[  {"nodeid":"weather"                                ,"measureid":"intemp"                             , "aggreg":["avg","min","max"]                                             ,"filter":"1 = 1 or 2 = 1"    }                      ,{"nodeid":"weather"                              ,"measureid":"intemp"                            , "aggreg":["avg"]                                           ,"filter":"2 = 1 or 2 = 2"   }     ]      }

Comment: Edit the question, code does not work well in comments

Comment: More info as I find it: In the JS of the two charts in the web page: Each JS there receives the same json reply (exactly the same). So each makes a different request but each receives the same rowset reply. (I added console.log to those JS's so I could see the flow in the web page.)

Comment: I have submitted a query to the mssql node developer. I will update this when I receive a reply.  Tom

Comment: Here is what I found/did. What a PITA. I changed the receiving node to accept the full message not just the payload; hoping that the ultimate ws node would not broadcast the response - no luck. I changed the JS in html to send an id with the payload that gets returned with the ws reply and then I compare it to the id i sent. If it is equal I accept the broadcast.,

Comment: If you have an answer please add it as an answer not a comment then it can be found by others